# Float Left is Going All the Way Right

Tags: html, css

When I try to Float my div to the left, it goes all the way to the right.  However, when I take float out of my CSS rule, it goes back to the left.

```css
.ShawHome {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ShawHome">sdfsdfsdf </div>
    <div class="KodiHome"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like when I use float:

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that we can see and replicate the issue. My guess is that you float the elements before it and don't clear it first, but without a complete example all we can do is hazard guesses.

Comment: There must be more to this than what you show.

Comment: @j08691 Well that was the issue at hand.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I added it as an answer, however you should really post a [mcve] to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're floating elements before your `<div class="container-fluid">` then you'll need to clear them in order for this div to appear after it. Use `clear:both` (or left or right if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Use clearfix before your floating div like this:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="ShawHome">sdfsdfsdf </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the **bootstrap framework**.  If that's the case, use `.pull-left` or `.pull-right` classes with the `.clearfix` class as the parent div.

If you are not using bootstrap then implement this code to your CSS:

```
 .pull-left{
   float: left!important;
  }
  .pull-right{
    float: right!important;
  }
 .clearfix{
  clear: both;
 }
 .clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
 }
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix
this might be helpful. i hope this helps.

Comment: @Shaun no idea what happened system rejected your proposal or may be it got rejected due to i was updating something. but i added them back.

Comment: Said something about a previous edit, it's all good.

Comment: yep, sorry its just got rejected by system. i added it back thanks for the updates. :)